# Automatically get to-be-used columns in SQL query (Hibernate/Mybatis/home-made)? - An idea to create a library

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, compilation, mybatis

We know we should not write `SELECT *`; instead, should write down the columns that will indeed be used in the business logic <sub>(e.g. `SELECT blog_title, blog_content` in one query about the full article, and `SELECT blog_title` in another logic that only cares about titles)</sub>.

However, in MyBatis or Hibernate, IMHO I have to write down those columns manually... This seems *really a waste of time*...

I wonder whether there is a way to make our lives easier? More specifically:

1. Is there any automatic way in Mybatis/Hibernate to do so?
2. If no, will my following naive idea works? (If so I am willing to create an open-source library.)

Two naive ideas (with Mybatis):

a. Statically analyze the Java syntax tree, and see who uses which columns.

b. Dynamically run the code once and get enough information about which columns will be used (maybe through a dynamic proxy like cglib).

Or, we will *have to* manually write down those columns by ourselves, without any good aids?? :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static analysis is pretty hard if your access is dynamic or in non-java files and analyzing performance problems is going to be very hard this way as well. Take a look at what [Blaze-Persistence Entity-View](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) has to offer which is almost what you want!

Comment: (a late reply after 4 months) I decided to do it manually, and writing `SELECT *` for non-performance-critical situations. This *is really* a hard problem for static analysis, after gaining more insights in these months.